# Getting Business Exception While retrieving Values from Service Reference while debugging

Tags: c#, exception

This is the error that I am getting. When I am trying to Go inside the Method using 'F11' it is not allowing me to and moreover am getting error (Screenshot attached. Please tell me is there any way I can debug this? I have googled it for God knows how many times but haven't had any luck ! Please help.[Error Screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3KWM.png)

Comment: This looks like a custom exception. You will need to speak to the Service owner about it

Comment: Thanks Bernd for your help :) but unfortunately we can't communicate with the Service Owner. We only have the URLs shared  using which we added the Service Reference. Is there any other way we can find out the error and resolve it ?

Comment: First check if there is any public API documentation and consult that. Otherwise you will need to look at the message in the exception and work from there to figure out what the problem is

Comment: The problem is there is no particular message or exception for this, but what ever i have attached in the screen shot. Hence the struggle. There is no Public API documentation either !

Comment: The message in the exception reads "message=No Records found in CISSearch 120008 - Search Contract - Contract not found". (Future hint: Please post the exception as text into your question, makes it a lot easier for us)

Comment: OK Sure ! :)  But any idea about the resolution of this issue ?

Comment: Cannot comment on the current issue. You will need to adjust your search criteria, inspect the objects being sent in to see what can be changed to get a result, etc. You will need to fiddle with the code